# Hiding symbols while building static library in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, ide, static-libraries

I'm looking for a way to hide symbols in a static library built in Visual Studio.  I've been able to do it in clang and gcc but I'm not sure if there's a way to do it in VS.

I am building a static library *parentlib* that needs to be built on Linux (using gcc), OSX (using clang), and Windows (using visual studio compiler).  This library makes use of 3 other libraries: *childliba, childlibb, childlibc*.

I have an API for *parentlib* and I want only the symbols pertaining to the API to be exposed in the library.  For example, if someone ran `nm parentlib` they wouldn't see any of the symbols in *childlib(abc)*

The way I do this when building the library using clang/gcc is:

```
clang -exported-symbols-list <text_file_with_parentlib_api_symbols> ...
gcc --globalize-symbols=<text_file_with_parentlib_api_symbols> ...
```

Now any symbols that aren't listed in the text file aren't made global in the resultant library.

Is there a way to set up this type of symbol hiding in Visual Studio?  I've looked around and asked multiple colleagues but no one seems to think it's possible.

Comment: I think this is more a question about Microsoft's PE/COFF format (and the `link` tool) than about C or VS. There's a 73-page (200 KB) long specification `pecoff.docx` [available here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19509), which looks like a good starting point to find out if it is at all possible to achieve the effect you want. (I was unable to find documentation pertaining the `-exported-symbols-list` and `--globalize-symbols` [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/genindex.html) or [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Index.html#Option-Index), btw)